# stacking up icons horizontally and responsive

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

need help on this one, I could not find any other solutions for this

basically what I need is to have a list of icons horizontally adjust on screen width

so if I have seven icons horizontally then when i'm in a tablet then the icons that wont fit will go to a certain div which has a slideup and down effect

so if ipad shows only 6 icons then the seventh icon will be on the div

I have an image for illustration

https://scontent-hkg.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s480x480/10561708_10206712852445687_4831295921092928962_n.jpg?oh=fb34cea324bdaf9dfbd104b8ff04698d&oe=557FD113

I could really need help on this, thanks

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oliver,

This is a bit of a broad question since there are a few ways you can go about this. I am sure there is a library or two out there which would help you accomplish this. If you plan to do it yourself you will want to start with the following tasks.

1. Detect when your screen size changes. This can be done with a timer or using the window.onresize event.
2. Once the screen size changes you will need examine your button elements and their wrapper to determine which elements are no longer on the screen.
3. Finally, you will want to move these overflow elements to your secondary navigation menu.

To help you get started I put together a simple example using jQuery to accomplish this task. See the JSFiddle at the bottom of this post for a complete, working example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get reference to our static elements 
    // one time at load for performance
    var $nav = $('nav');
    var $primaryList = $nav.find('.primary-list ul');
    var $overflowList = $nav.find('.overflow-list ul');
    var $overflowButton = $('#show-overflow');

    // Bind our overflow toggle for the overflow list
    $overflowButton.click(function() {
        $nav.toggleClass('show-overflow');
    });

    // Bind our resize event so we know when
    // viewport size changes
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // Find our last item in primary list
        var $pl = $primaryList.find('li:last');
        // Figure out the right side of our last element
        var x = $pl.position().left + $pl.outerWidth();
        var listWidth = $primaryList.innerWidth();
        // Check to see if this is outside of our menu
        if (x > listWidth) {
            // Since this is outside we move it to overflow
            $pl.prependTo($overflowList);
            // Show our overflow button
            $overflowButton.show();
        } else {
            // Since this didn't overflow lets see if we have enough
            // room to move an overflow element back to the primary list
            var $ol = $overflowList.find('li:first');
            // Check to see if we found an overflow element
            if ($ol.length > 0) {
                // Check to see if this one will fit
                if (x + $ol.outerWidth() <= listWidth) {
                    // Move it back to the primary list
                    $ol.appendTo($primaryList);
                }
            } else {
                // Hide our overflow button
                $overflowButton.hide();
            }
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gayv02gy/2/

Cheers!

Comment: No problem Oliver. Good luck!

Comment: sorry I cannot voteup because I still need 15 reputation for that

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer such question more on-target without a *code sample* of what you are building. There are uncountable ways you can achieve such result. For this reason, I will try to answer you presenting the most simplistic code I can possibly conceive (no JS, only in-line CSS and HTML).

Try the code snippet below:

```html
<div style="width:100%; height: 30px; margin: auto auto; text-align:center; display:block; border:1px solid yellow;">
  <span style="width:30px; height: 30px; border:1px solid orange; display:inline-block;">A</span>
  <span style="width:30px; height: 30px; border:1px solid red; display:inline-block;">B</span>
  <span style="width:30px; height: 30px; border:1px solid green; display:inline-block;">C</span>
  <span style="width:30px; height: 30px; border:1px solid blue; display:inline-block;">D</span>
  <span style="width:30px; height: 30px; border:1px solid pink; display:inline-block;">E</span>
</div>
```

Note that the only required CSS in the "SPAN" objects to allow it to be auto-centered is: "**display: inline-block**".

The "DIV" container, on the other hand, requires exactly what you see in the in-line CSS (other than the **border**, of course, which is there only to help you visualize the result).

Enjoy coding. ;)

Comment: hi there, I have been struggling all these days trying to figure it out, thanks